# Excel Graph - Cell with Formula to act as Empty Cell in Graph

Tags: excel

I'm using a set of monthly data to create a graph (i.e. one number for each month) - the cell I'm using for the graph has a formula so there are not any truly empty cells in the dataset.

I would like for the graph to appear as if the cells that are null due to the formula are actually treated as empty cells so there are no points at zero and no lines connecting the points (similar to Example 1 in the image). The only options I have found thus far are the other 2 examples in the image.

Example 2: using an if statement with ,"" at the end and the chart referring to "Null" fields as zero and the lines connecting to each point

Example 3" using an if statement with ,NA() at the end and the chart referring to these fields as #N/A but the graph is still connecting all of the points and skipping over the fields with #N/A

My goal is for the graph to look like Example 1 but still be able to incorporate the if statement in the table.

[Excel Graph Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmxcE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using another chart type? Since the data is not continuous, maybe you could use **Column chart** or **Scatter chart**.

See examples:

[image]